# Parallax scrolling of separate div (with ‘position: absolute’ and slideshow background)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have website with a menu on top, then a banner that spans 70% of the page (height), below there’s the content of the page. In the banner I have a jQuery slideshow covering the whole window. I want to add parallax scrolling to this slideshow background that is visible through the “empty” banner.

My setup is like that the background with slideshow is a separate div before all other content on the site and then set it to ‘position: absolute’ and ‘z-index: -100’.

Beacause if I let the div with the background span over all other content, all that content is parallax scrolled and not the background only…

**So how can I make a seperate div parallax scroll?**

Take a look at my demonstration at [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dpZML/2/).

*Simplification of HTML:*

```
<body>
    <div id="parallax-bg"></div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div class="banner"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

*Simplification of CSS:*

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-100;
}
#parallax-bg {
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-100;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
#menu {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

*Script used to parallex scrolling:*

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

    jQuery('#bg').css({
        'top': -(jQuery(this).scrollTop() / 2) + "px"
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at [parallax.js](http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/) and [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)

Comment: @Xero It feels little bit to much for my case. Isn't there any simple script that moves a divs position when scrolling?

Comment: Probably, but stellar is simple to use.  It just takes a few extra attributes: `data-stellar-ratio=""` and a little code snippet in the script `$.stellar();` that's all.

Comment: @Xero Thank you for responding. Yeah, I tried putting "$.stellar();" in a <script>, and loaded stellar.js. And put data-stellar-ratio="2" at my #bg. But doesn't work...

Comment: did you remember to put the `stellar.js` below the `jquery.js`. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n25MJ/ , because stellar requires jQuery.

Comment: @Xero Yes, I did... there's a jQuery-script called bgswitcher, that i use to change backgrounds on that element (#bg). I put a exact same element but without that script to it. And then it worked for that test element... hmm. Any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed that in your JSFiddle, it was `#parallax-bg`, instead of `#bg`, was this an accident, or intentional?

Comment: @Xero Yeah, sorry.. I actually have a completely other name in my real code :) With #bg i mean #parallax-bg (and #video-bg that it is in my code)... sorry. So, maybe it could be fixed by using a simpler background changer script? Is there one out there that just replaces the url link, and makes it fade, nothing more?